# One-Way Replication Into Different Schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, database-replication, database-administration

I'm looking for the best (best practice) option for one way replication between two databases.  I would like to keep this purely SQL but, can write something in C# or use an ETL tool if there are no other good options.

**Current setup:**
DB1 - There are three instances of this database.  It is a large relational database, the schema is the same for each but, they are separate data pots (no replication).  Two databases on a 2012 server and one on a 2014 server

DB2 - There are two instances of this database on seperate servers (Europe, Americas) and the data is merge replicated between the two.  The publisher is the 2014 server.

[image]

**The Goal:**
DB2 is tied to some reports.  It has one table and a small application attached to that table.  Users from many different countries enter data via a small application into DB2 and generate reports out of the application.

DB1 is a relational database that has a very large application on top of it but with fewer users.  If users are using the application for DB1 then they should not need to duplicate their records into DB2.

There should be one-way replication from the multiple seperate DB1s into DB2. How quickly this happens is not too important.

The important things are:

- No backwards replication occurs from DB2s > DB1s (Data only flows from DB1s into one of the DB2s)
- Create, Update, and Delete actions should occur in DB2 based on the results
  of a comparisson with DB1 (the one way replication)

**Current Approach:**
I currently have a flat *sql view* on each DB1 database that has the same schema as the table in the DB2 db's that the data needs to go into.

The servers are also joined as linked servers.

My though was to do a sort of manually written replication script on one of the DB2 databases that calls the views from the DB1s and does the CUD actions on a timed basis.

It seems to me that there should be an easier way though!?

Any thoughts on how to do this would be very much appreciated.

Keep in mind that since several of the DB1s exist on a SQL 2012 server that there may be some issues as 2012 might not be allowed to be a publisher for replication to a 2014 server.

Comment: If the tables that you're looking to replicate into DB2 each have a primary key, you can use transactional replication.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the suggestion.  I tried to do a transact replication on this but, it claims that the tables referencing the view from DB1 need to exist in DB2.  Since the DB2 database is essentially a single table and the relational tables that form the view for DB1 = 6, it seems like it would add a lot of clutter and size to DB2.

Comment: If you're not replicating tables, what *are* you replicating? Based on all of the above, my assumption was that you were looking to replicate the tables (i.e "the data"). You can replicate a view, but either it will be the view definition only or, if it's an indexed view, you can replicate the view's materialized state.

Comment: So all DB1s have the same schema, relational, many tables.  All DB2s have the same schema as well, basically just a single table.  I created a view in the DB1s that has the same schema as the DB2 table that data needs to go into.  So yep, looking to replicate "the data" one way from the DB1 view (3 seperate db's currently) to the DB2 table.  As for keys, there is one that I can link on, it will be a FK in DB2.